# insert Cross-Tab to Crystal report and use as summarized field the running totals

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I am new to Crystal. I have a report in which I formatted the Detail section so as to suppress duplicate rows under a condition. I have a running total at every group section to sum a field's value using the opposite of the previous condition so as to exclude the hidden rows from the total. So far, so good.
I now want to add a front section of the report as a summary and I inserted a Cross-tab at the beginning of the report. The field that I want to be displayed as the summarized field is the running total. But it doesn't excludes the hidden rows, it just does a sum of the field. 
I am trying to give a more clear example below. Any ideas? Thank you.

*Department A

*Week 1

-Field1 Field2 Field3

-Field1 Field2 Field3 //duplicate row,  suppress and not be a part of the sum

-Field1 Field2 Field3

```
         -Sum(Field3)  // (row1+row3)
```

Cross Tab
           **Department1**

**Week1**     Sum(Field3)  //row1+row2+row3